# Assigning values to HTML elements from an array

Tags: jquery

I have four button elements, and I want each to be populated with a value from an array called `option`, which contains the values: 10, 20, 30, 40.

In the code below, I attempt to load each button with an ascending index of the array, but they all display '40'.

```js
let test = {
  question: "1+1=?",
  option: [10, 20, 30, 40]
}

$(".questionPage button").text(test.option[0])
$(".questionPage button").text(test.option[1])
$(".questionPage button").text(test.option[2])
$(".questionPage button").text(test.option[3])
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 300px;
}

.questionPage {
  background-color: rgb(124, 50, 50);
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div class="questionPage">
  <h1>Question 1</h1>
  <br>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Aperiam quaerat ipsum praesentium voluptatum voluptatem consequuntur optio ipsa quam quis id! Placeat, voluptates minus tempore vitae perferendis provident id esse numquam?</p>
  <br>
  <button>1.option</button>
  <button>2.option</button>
  <br>
  <button>3.option</button>
  <button>4.option</button>
</div>
```

what happen ? how can i do ?

Comment: Set each button with different class, and call the class with jQuery

Comment: try like this, each tag button with jQuery ```$('button').each(function(index, value) { $(this).text(test.option[index]) });```

Answer (score 0):

use "var" instead of let

```
let test = {
  question: "1+1=?",
  option: [10, 20, 30, 40]
}
```

its working for sure.

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning your values to the same set of buttons each time. `$(".questionPage button")` always refers to the same set of buttons, so every time you call `text(test.option[*])` it overwrites *all* of your buttons.

You could to use more specific class names, assign an `id` to each button, or place your buttons in an array and iterate over the array to assign a value to each.

I would recommend placing your buttons in an array and iterating to make the assignments.